# Function to shorten Queries not working

Tags: php, sql, function

Here is my code:

```
function query($query, $variables = NULL) {
    $execute = sprintf($query, $variables);
    $execute = mysql_query($execute);

    return $execute;
}

$insert = query("INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, validation_code, registration_timestamp, registration_ip) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", "$username, $email, $passwordEncrypted, $validationCode, $timestamp, $ip");
```

If there is only one variable, it will work. But with any after that it wont. Any suggestions on how to fix & improve this function? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite it to:

```
function query($query, $variables = array()) {
    $execute = vprintf($query, $variables);
    $execute = mysql_query($execute);

    return $execute;
}

$insert = query("INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, validation_code, registration_timestamp, registration_ip) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", array($username, $email, $passwordEncrypted, $validationCode, $timestamp, $ip));
```

Btw, I absolutely agree with @Alex and you need to move to mysqli/PDO prepared statements instead.

PS: don't forget to apply `mysql_real_escape_string` to each variable.

Comment: @alex: OMG, never know there is such function :-S

Comment: Thanks that worked. I actually have never looked into mysqli/PDO. Might be something to look into

Comment: False alarm. I have run into an issue. I am getting "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in" errors and it is echoing my queries?

Comment: @Marcus Krueger: well, have you tried to look what is wrong with your queries? `mysql_error()` + `var_dump(vprintf($query, $variables))`

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a string when you should be passing it directly an array to your function.

However, you shouldn't me making a wrapper for `mysql_query()` when better alternatives exist, such as PDO.

Comment: What if there is a comma in any variable? ;-P

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, a pitfall of trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function query()
{
    $query = call_user_func_array('sprintf',func_get_args());
    return mysql_query($query);
}
```

and then use like so:

```
$insert = query(
    "INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, validation_code, registration_timestamp, registration_ip) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
    $username,
    $email,
    $passwordEncrypted,
    $validationCode,
    $timestamp,
    $ip
);
```